# Using Python shell as substitute to websockets

Tags: javascript, python, websocket, server, quasar-framework

im having a setup on raspberry pi where I am creating a python server running in background for handle the communication with raspberry pi:s GPIO. In the frontend I am running a [Quasar framework](https://quasar.dev/) application. This works fine but I just found out you can use a node module called "[python shell](https://www.npmjs.com/package/python-shell)" for the communication.

Since this was new to me Im interested if there are any advantages using this instead of communicate through websockets? Can it basically do the same thing or what is the differences?

Comment: But node modules are backend by definition; I don't see how that will replace the websocket connection between Quasar client and whatever server you have? The module is just a different way of running Python code in your node environment, instead of the usual child process spawning (which it does under the hood anyway).

Comment: It seems convenient though since I dont have to manually run a python script with '''python server.py''' which im now are autostarting at startup. Maybe there are more advantages or is it just about the same ...

Comment: I'm using a PHP backend on my Pi for that reason but I don't really need real-time communication though. Still, assuming the websockets communication is between Quasar and the python server, you'd simply replace the python server with a node server running python scripts. Seems like more work, not less.